# Swift 3 How to order / sort contents of [[String]]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

```
var array = [["Sally", "3", "blue"], ["Jack", "6", "green"], ["Harold", "2", "yellow"]]
```

I am trying to order the contents of this `[[String]]` based on the first index of each value (ordering by the names; Sally, Jack, Harold).

Is there a Swift 3 method that I can use to order these automatically? Or, is there some loop I can create that will iterate through these inner arrays to sort them based on the names of the people?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as simple as it can be:

```
var array = [["Sally", "3", "blue"], ["Jack", "6", "green"], ["Harold", "2", "yellow"]]

array.sort { $0.first! < $1.first! } // [["Harold", "2", "yellow"], ["Jack", "6", "green"], ["Sally", "3", "blue"]]
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you explained the meaning of `$0` and `$1`, as not everyone may know it.

Comment: ... Or flagging this question as a duplicate.

Comment: My apologies, I asked this question because I was having troubles with solutions from other questions. But when I checked over my code I found out it was something on my end.

Nonetheless this solution now works fine. Thank you very much!